# PHP Namespaces in different files

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces

I am developing my own & small MVC framework for my portfolio and as barebone for future developments.

I encountered a problem which I couldn't solve for an good hour.

I am using composer to build autoload files as well as namespaces.

I have a baseController which is very simple at moment but the problem I got is that for some reason I cannot extend it from the default controller which I'm trying to create.

This is my welcomeController.php file (extends baseController):

```
<?php
namespace AppWorld\Controls;
use AppWorld\FrostHeart;

class landingController extends baseController {

public function index() {

    $data['foo'] = "Foo";
    $data['bar'] = "Bar";

    $this->View->show('landingpage', $data, $showTemplate = 0);
}

}
```

This is my baseController.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppWorld\FrostHeart;

class baseController {

    //@var::View - Instance of View object
    public $currentView;

    public function __construct() {

        //Start the session
        session_start();

        //Create new view object
        $this->currentView = new View();
    }
}
```

I have tried all combinations of name spaces because I was so helpless but I was still unable to solve the problem.

welcomeController.php is in root/application/controllers namespaced as AppWorld\Controls

baseController.php is in root/application/core namespaced as AppWorld\FrostHeart

@Edit:
That's the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AppWorld\FrostHeart\baseController' not found in D:\Software\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controller\landingController.php on line 5
```

@Edit2:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "simplymvc",
    "description": "Simple MVC with options to expand upon",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "0.0.1-dev",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Maciej Olborski",
            "email": "olbi123@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://maciejolborski.net",
            "role": "Lead"
        }
    ],
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.6.8"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4":{
                "AppWorld\\": "application",
                "AppWorld\\Conffy\\": "application/config",
                "AppWorld\\FrostHeart\\": "application/core",
                "AppWorld\\Controls\\": "application/controller"
            }
        }
}
```

@Edit3

So this is Application.php:

```
<?php
namespace AppWorld\FrostHeart;

class Application {

    // $var::Mixed - Instance of the controller
    private $controller;
    // $var::Array - Parameters passed to the URL
    private $parameters = array();  
    // $var::String - Current controller name
    private $controller_name;
    // $var::String - Current method name
    private $method_name;

    public function __construct() {
        //Prepare URL and set URL parameters
        $this->prepareURL();
        //Check if controller and/or method are not empty
        $this->checkControllerAndMethod();

        //Check if controller file exists?
        if(file_exists(CONTROLLER_DIR . $this->controller_name . ".php")) 
        {
            //Load controller file and and create this controller
            require(CONTROLLER_DIR . $this->controller_name . ".php");

            $this->controller = new $this->controller_name();

            //Check if the method exists within this controller
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $this->method_name)) 
            {                               
                // call method and pass parameters to this method
                call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, $this->method_name), $this->parameters);
            } 
            else 
            {
                //When no parameters are given just call method without parameters
                $this->controller->{$this->method_name}();
            }
        }
    }

    private function prepareURL() {

        //GET URL and split it to URL Segments
        $params = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $params = trim($params, '/');
        $params = filter_var($params, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $params = explode('/', $params);

        //Set controller name to first URL Segment within GET['action']
        $this->controller_name = $params[0];
        //Set method name to first URL Segment within GET['action']
        $this->method_name = $params[1];     

        unset($params[0], $params[1]);

        //Store array of parameters(URL Segments) to parameters array
        $this->parameters = array_values($params);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * This method checks if the controller and/or method was provided in the URL 
     * If the controller and/or method was not provided then defaults are loaded from config file.
     * Also renames the Controller name so it's landingController not just landing.
     * 
     */

    private function checkControllerAndMethod() {

        //Check whether the controller_name is set if not load default controller
        if(!$this->controller_name) 
        {
            $this->controller_name = DEFAULT_CONTROLLER;
        }

        //Check whether the method_name is set if not load default method
        if(!$this->method_name || strlen($this->method_name) === 0) 
        {
            $this->method_name = DEFAULT_METHOD;
        }

        //Rename the controller_name so that it contains "Controller" word after the name
        $this->controller_name = $this->controller_name . 'Controller';

        /**
        echo 'Controller: ' . $this->controller_name;
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Method: ' . $this->method_name;
        **/
    }
}
```

If this line is commented:

```
$this->controller = new $this->controller_name();
```

and this line is commented:

```
$this->controller->{$this->method_name}();
```

then I can see all files being loaded properly including the base and landing controller but if I leave them uncommented the error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'landingController' not found in D:\Software\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\core\Application.php on line 27

Comment: Please post your autoloading config from composer.json

Comment: I've now added it its @Edit2

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `use` line to `use AppWorld\FrostHeart\baseController;`

Comment: I've tried that as well as other combinations I could think of

Comment: that part is definitely an error, so fix that and try it again and see if your error changes at all.

Comment: you might also try running `composer dumpautoload` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: also i'm seeing that your namespaces are not matching your folder structure. it really keeps things simple if you make sure they always match.

Comment: I know that the namespaces doesn't match folder structure but that's on purpose, I just like it like that, gets me out of boredom! :D

Comment: fair enough, what happens when you fix the use line?

Comment: Though I edited the file I have re-generated autoload files but the error is still exactly the same. :(

Comment: you fixed the `use` line but the error is the same?

Comment: Yes, Fatal error: Class 'AppWorld\FrostHeart\baseController' not found in D:\Software\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controller\landingController.php on line 5

Comment: ok, keep the use line fixed, because that is one problem that needs fixing.  just to cover the obvious, are you including `vendor/autoload.php` before this?

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's not. I've just debugged it at top level (index.php in root) using 
foreach(get_included_files() as $key => $value) {
    echo $key[$value];
}
and it only shows that the landingController.php is loaded but the autoload.php and config.php doesnt show either even I am using config constants as well as using Namespace to create instance of application

Comment: at the very start of your index.php try adding `include 'vendor/autoload.php';` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I've got a weird issue here, all files are loaded if two lines of code are removed from Application.php (that's the bootstrap) but when they are added back the code breaks. I've added @Edit3 for you to check.

Comment: about this code: `require(CONTROLLER_DIR . $this->controller_name . ".php");`  ... you shouldn't need to be doing this. that is what autoloading is for.

Comment: also [read up on PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and re-think why you want to use PSR4 in composer.json but not actually use PSR4 in your namespace